# How to do a double array enum lookup

Tags: java, arrays, enums, coordinates, lookup

I've declared an enum of id and description and double array for coordinates.

```
public enum Location {
    GRASS(0, "Green Grass"),
    CHURCH(1, "A church");

    private int locationId;
    public int locationId() { return locationId; }

    private String description;
    public String details(){ return description; }

    Location(int locationId, String description){
        this.locationId = locationId;
        this.description = description;
    }
```

I have then declared my array of locations...

```
private Location[][] locations;
```

I then setup a load of random locations for the width and height of my map...

```
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            locations[x][y] = Math.random() < 0.5 ? Location.GRASS: Location.CHURCH;
        }
    }
```

now i want to loop through the set of locations and pull out the locationId from tiles[x][y]

```
    int locationID;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            locationID = locations[x][y].WHATGOESHERE?
            Debug.e("Current location: " + locationID);
        }
    }
```

How do I pull back the first element of Location at this point? I want the numeric value of that particular Location at x y.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `locations[x][y]` gives you a `Location`, so just call the proper method here:

```
locationID = locations[x][y].locationId();
```

Comment: Doh. Thanks. i kept trying to access it like an array, been up too long.